# VueJS Разница между Methods и Computed

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

Недавно начал учить Vue и сразу-же застрял на таком моменте

1) Что такое Methods 
2) Что такое Computed
3) В чем их разница
4) Когда что применять.

У меня есть курс на Udemy но этот момент я никак не могу понять до этого все ясно но тут беда.

Answer (score 1):

**Кеширование вычисляемых свойств**

Вы могли заметить, что того же результата можно достигнуть при помощи метода:

```
<p>Сообщение задом наперёд: "{{ reverseMessage() }}"</p>

// в компоненте
methods: {
  reverseMessage: function () {
    return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
  }
}
```

Вместо вычисляемого свойства, мы можем указать ту же самую функцию в качестве метода. С точки зрения конечного результата, оба подхода действительно делают одно и то же. Но есть важное различие: **вычисляемые свойства кешируются, основываясь на своих зависимостях**. Вычисляемое свойство будет пересчитано только тогда, когда изменится одна из его зависимостей. Поэтому, пока `message` остаётся неизменным, многократное обращение к `reversedMessage` будет каждый раз незамедлительно возвращать единожды вычисленное значение, не запуская функцию вновь.

Кроме того, это значит, что следующее вычисляемое свойство никогда не обновится, так как `Date.now()` не является реактивной зависимостью:

```
computed: {
  now: function () {
    return Date.now()
  }
}
```

Использование метода, напротив, запускает функцию **всегда, при каждом обращении к нему**.

Зачем нужно кеширование? Представьте, что у вас есть дорогое вычисляемое свойство **A**, требующее цикла по огромному массиву и выполняющее множество вычислений. А ещё пусть будут другие вычисляемые свойства, в свою очередь, зависящие от **A**. Без кеширования геттер **A** будет запускаться куда чаще необходимого! В тех же случаях, когда кеширования нужно избежать — используйте методы.

P.S.: Взято с [официального мануала](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). Судя по описанию можно сказать что `computed` кешируется, а `methods` вызывается каждый раз.